# Customizing/Deleting an adaptive card after it has been sent in boframework

Tags: botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I'm making a bot that sends a user a list of requests that have to be accepted or rejected so I want to disable the card or delete it or disable the submit button whenever the user accepts or rejects a request.

Is that possible? and if not, what are the other alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: No. Once you have sent the card it's gone. The client application renders it, and shows it to the user, and the cards are not dynamic (ie cannot contain scripts). If the user interacts with the card you will get a postback, but you cannot change the existing card, you can only send another card or message.

Comment: Which channel do you want to integrate with your bot? If you embed webchat in a website, you might be able to achieve the requirement by dynamically applying the specified css style to submit button on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stuartd replied: 
No. Once you have sent the card it's gone. The client application renders it, and shows it to the user, and the cards are not dynamic (ie cannot contain scripts). If the user interacts with the card you will get a postback, but you cannot change the existing card, you can only send another card or message.